# Insert documents mapped to a _class from existing documents mapped to a different _class

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I want to insert documents that are mapped to a _class : org.some.package.class2
from all documents that already exist (in the same bucket) and are mapped to another _class org.some.package.class2.
I want preserve the same structure of the existing documents.
Example:
I want to create this document

```
{
  "name": "Doe",
  "firstName": "Joe"
  "phone": "[
      "0123456789", "0987654321"
    ]",
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "_class": "org.some.package.class1"
}
```

from

```
{
  "name": "Doe",
  "firstName": "Joe"
  "phone": "[
      "0123456789", "0987654321"
    ]",
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "_class": "org.some.package.class2"
}
```

Comment: This seems like a simple `UPDATE`, is there any reason why that wouldn't work?

Comment: As  Mathew Groves mentioned use Update. If you need to duplicate the documents and change _class use INSERT INTO ..... SELECT ...